# How to create an algorithm that accepts an audio file in any format using Python?

Tags: python, api

I want to create an algorithm that accepts an audio file. for now i just want to store it in some database or extract info from it. there are ready-made modules that can do this but it's all limited and I want to make my own. Any ideas or help?

Comment: Do you actually want to transcode or play the audio file, or just store the binary data? Writing your own code to do anything more than just store the file or extract some metadata sounds like a lot of work for no real gain: I'd work out how to work with the libraries instead. What are the problems with the libraries?

Comment: But if you really want to start from scratch yourself, the simple answer is 1) work out all the file formats you want to support 2) find specifications for all of them 3) write some code for each one.

Comment: actually i was creating an API that accepts any format of audio file but i dont know how. im new to APIs